# One input required only

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to check if one of these inputs are filled, but is not working fine.
The rules are:

1. If two fields are filled enable the button
2. If field 1 (text1) is filled and field 2 (text2) is empty, enable the button.
3. If field 2 (text2) is filled and field 1 (text1) is empty, enable the button.
4. If both are empty don't enable the button.
   Have idea about what's is wrong? Thank you!

```js
if (($('[name=text1]').val() != '') && ($('[name=text2]').val() != '')) {
  $('[name=text1]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
  $('[name=text2]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
  console.log("C1");
} else if (($('[name=text1]').val() != '') && ($('[name=text2]').val() == '')) {
  $('[name=text2]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
  $('[name=text1]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
  console.log("C2");
} else if (($('[name=text1]').val() == '') && ($('[name=text2]').val() != '')) {
  $('[name=text2]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
  $('[name=text1]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
  console.log("C3");
} else {
  $('[name=text1]').parent().removeClass('filled').addClass('empty started bloked');
  $('[name=text2]').parent().removeClass('filled').addClass('empty started bloked');
  console.log("C4");
}
```

```css
input[name="text1"],
input[name="text2"] {
  border: 1px green solid;
}

.filled input[name="text1"],
.filled input[name="text2"] {
  border: 1px green solid;
}

.empty input[name="text1"],
.started input[name="text1"],
.bloked input[name="text1"],
.empty input[name="text2"],
.started input[name="text2"],
.bloked input[name="text2"] {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.buy-button {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.buy-button.enable {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="detailsSku__names">

  <div class="detailsSku__label">
    <input type="text" placeholder="text 1*" name="text1" class="text1" data-target="previewText1" maxlength="11">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="detailsSku__label">
    <input type="text" placeholder="text 2" value="" name="text2" class="text2" data-target="previewText2" maxlength="11">
  </div>

</div>
<a class="buy-button" href="#">Comprar</a>
```

Comment: You are not enabling/disabling your buttons in any of your cases, or at least not in the code you shared with us.

Comment: Disable button from start. On KeyUp-Listener on both inputs do the checks and enable/disable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the modifications I made.

```
<button id="buy-button" disabled=true>Comprar</button>

<script>
$('input[name="text1"], input[name="text2"]').on('blur',function(){
var a = $('.text1').val().trim().length;
var b = $('.text2').val().trim().length;
if (a!=0 && b!=0){
    $('#buy-button').attr('disabled', false);
} else if (a!=0 && b==0) {
    $('#buy-button').attr('disabled', false);
} else if (b!=0 && a==0) {
    $('#buy-button').attr('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#buy-button').attr('disabled', true);
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Its because you are using AND.

```
if (($('[name=text1]').val() != '') || ($('[name=text2]').val() != '')) {
   if ($('[name=text1]').val() != '') {
      $('[name=text1]').parent().removeClass('empty started  bloked').addClass('filled'); 
   }else{
      $('[name=text2]').parent().removeClass('empty started bloked').addClass('filled');
   }
}else {
   $('[name=text1]').parent().removeClass('filled').addClass('empty started bloked');
   $('[name=text2]').parent().removeClass('filled').addClass('empty started bloked');
}
```